What is the ambiguity in the sentence "I know a man who has a dog with fleas"
Ambiguity's two types are lexical and structural.

Please show some effort or explaination why this problem is unclear for you.

@KillingTime Why have you linked this to a question that is completely unrelated in any meaningful way?

Related.

It can be parsed in two ways:

I know [a man who has a dog] with fleas.
I know a man who has a [dog with fleas].

So either the man or the dog could be the one with fleas.
In practice it's not ambiguous at all, for two reasons:

Fleas usually infest dogs, not people.
If there's nothing else to go on, a prepositional phrase usually connects with the closest preceding noun or verb that makes sense.

